# A first element should take a free space and next elements should have fixed size

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to set for fist element '1fr' and any other elements should have fixed size

I'm tried this and it works.

```
grid-template-columns: 500px repeat(auto-fill, 50px);
```

This, what I'm trying to do.

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(auto-fill, 50px);
    > div {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
  }
```

A first element should have a 1fr (any available space)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4PHL.png)

Comment: But `1fr` means `100% wide, so your requirement makes no sense.

Comment: so, how to resolve this issue? 
repeat(auto-fill, 50px) and first element should takes all free space.

because this it works grid-template-columns: auto repeat(4, 50px);, but I dont' know how to use auto-fill..

Comment: You can't....I'm pretty sure. This sounds like you need flexbox.

Comment: Could you give me an example of this case in the flexbox ?

Comment: Perhaps you could post an image of what this is expected to look like?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qPRSU4Z

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think flexbox would be more appropriate here.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 98vh;
  margin: 1vh 1vw;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin: .5em;
}

.wide {
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item wide">Auto Remaining Width</div>
  <div class="item">50px</div>
  <div class="item">50px</div>
  <div class="item">50px</div>
</div>
```